# cannot embed a secure rtmp stream aired by another website

Tags: javascript, php, html5-video, jwplayer, rtmp

i am trying to embed a live streaming rtmp on my website, but it always throws an error " can not connect to server". Here's the URL of the stream : http://goo.gl/zoVwIw

Please note that this stream is aired by another website and is not under my control.

i tried embedding the stream with jwplayer and videojs but its not working.

Please advice.

Comment: forgot to add: The channel streams perfectly through rtmpdump.

Comment: why is it stealing ? i am just trying to use my custom player.

Comment: It's stealing because the owner of the stream is probably showing that stream on his own page, complete with things like advertising to cover his costs. You, on the other hand, are trying to grab that stream to show on your own website, thereby bypassing the owner of the stream. That's why it's stealing.

Comment: Indeed, a lot of servers restrict RTMP streams to specific domains.

Answer (score 1):

So you're asking us how to steal someone else's content? Is that right? RTMP is a Flash protocol, and if you don't control the source of the stream, you can't provide the proper cross-domain security. In short, you can't get there from here.

Comment: so its not possible ?

Comment: If you can't place a crossdomain.xml file on the server that's providing the stream (a file that lists your domain as having permission to access the stream), then you can't get to that stream from your own domain.